# how to hide nivo slider caption area and make slides clicable

Tags: jquery, css, slider, nivo-slider

I have a nivo slider on my page, but I can't figure out how to have the slides clickable to pages and to remove the bottom area where the caption goes? 
Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<a href="/GrantInfo/NonProfitPartners.html"><img src="nivo-slider/demo/images/moorecenter.jpg" data-thumb="images/moorecenter.jpg"/></a>
<a href="/GrantInfo/NonProfitPartners.html"><img src="nivo-slider/demo/images/AIR.jpg" data-thumb="images/AIR.jpg" alt="AIR Seacoast" data-transition="slideInLeft"/></a>
<a href="/Programs+Publications/Publications.html"><img src="nivo-slider/demo/images/circle.jpg" data-thumb="images/circle-program.jpg" alt="Circle Program Plymouth" data-transition="slideInLeft"/></a>
<a href="/GrantInfo/NonProfitPartners.html"><img src="nivo-slider/demo/images/wholevillage.jpg" data-thumb="images/wholevillage.jpg" alt="Whole Village Plymouth"/></a>
</div></div>
```

Here is the CSS for the captions:

```
.nivo-caption {
display: none !important;
}

.nivo-html-caption {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the test site http://wfnh.org/test/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Got it removed using following code:

> div.nivo-caption {    display: none !important; }

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help, this is how I've got it setup for Wordpress, so if you're using straight HTML just put the link in, then an image within that, then close the link.

```
<div class="nivoSlider">
    <?php if(get_field('banner_images')): ?>
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('banner_images')): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo the_sub_field('image_link', $row); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo the_sub_field('image', $row); ?>" alt="Site Name" title="<?php echo the_sub_field('image_description'); ?>" />
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove the caption (description) area wherever it is in bottom or middle add the following style

```
.nivoSlider-desc { display: none;    }
```